# How to overlap widgets by respecting their sizes at Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I just want to overlap 2 `Container` by respecting first `Container`'s width.

This is what I want to achieve.

[image]

`Containers` not occupying space When I use `Stack` Widget. So I think stack widget not working for me.

And It is not overlapping when I use `Row`. So Row is not working either.

[image]

In CSS I just give negative margin to the right element and it is done. But I couldn't figure out the way to achieve that in flutter.

I put these `Containers` in to the Stack. Because I have to overflow a Card widget with that `Containers`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is my trial.

Using Stack and set 'clipBehavior: Clip.none' parameter.

Added 'addPostFrameCallback' method to get a left container's width.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  double firstContainerWidth = 0;
  GlobalKey firstContainerKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      firstContainerWidth = firstContainerKey.currentContext.size.width;
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: _buildBody(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    return Stack(
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomStart,
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
            left: firstContainerWidth - 10,
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 5),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.orange[400],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
              ),
              child: Text(
                'Ends after 1 hour',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 15,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            key: firstContainerKey,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 5),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.red,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
            ),
            child: Text(
              '%40 Discount',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Container's width is not fixed. So I cannot use `right: -135`

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you

You can use Stack Widget for [that](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html)

```
  Container(
      height: 60,
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 4), 
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned.fill(
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.yellow,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: Radius.circular(6),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(6),
                ),
              ),
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              child: Text('Ends after 1 Hour'),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.redAccent,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: Radius.circular(6),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(6),
                ),
              ),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8, left: 20),
              child: Text('40% Discount'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

Your result screen ->[image]

Comment: Nice approach but not working for me. Cause I'm using your top Container in the Stack. If I don't give width to your Top Container it gives `'constraints.biggest.isFinite': is not true` error

Comment: its working for me correct and Iam not give any width of container

Comment: It gives me error because I use That widgets in another Stack

Comment: I have to put it in another Stack. I will upload new image to the question to clarify why I have to use another Stack.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in multiple ways. You can use `CustomPainter`, `Stack` or even `Row` to do this. Here is my approach using a Row only.

**Result**

[image: Result]

**Code : [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/237fff42e4a114f89458a163bd94e8e6)**

```
class DiscountBadgeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
      children: [
        _buildRedSection(),
        _buildMiddleSection(),
        _buildYellowSection(),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildMiddleSection() => Container(
    color: Colors.yellow,
    child: Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      heightFactor: .5,
      child: Container(
        height: 80,
        width: 10,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.red,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.horizontal(right: Radius.circular(10)),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );

  Widget _buildRedSection() => Container(
    height: 80,
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.red,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.horizontal(left: Radius.circular(10)),
    ),
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right:6),
    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
    child: Text('40% Discount'),
  );

  Widget _buildYellowSection() => Container(
    height: 60,
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.yellow,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.horizontal(right: Radius.circular(10)),
    ),
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16, left:6),
    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
    child: Text('Ends after 1 Hour'),
  );
}
```